# What is the difference between a topic and a message?

Tags: ros, messages, topic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A very newbie question for sure, but I'm having a little trouble distinguishing between topics and messages. I understand that topics are the named "channels" published and subscribed by nodes and messages are the details of the data carried on the topics so they seem like pretty much the same thing. Can you ever have multiple message types sent across one topic? If not then why the distinction between the two?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/63511/what-is-the-difference-between-a-topic-and-a-message?/) by [cbgrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/4978/cbgrey/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2013-05-26

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you said, the topic is the channel where nodes are subscribed for to read messages or where the nodes publish those messages. The topic can be seen as a tag of certain type of data, and the message is the data itself, previously defined. Also, another reason for the difference between topic and message is that you can use two topics that share the same type of messages.

For Example:

Topics: Front_Laser_data, Rear_Laser_data

Message: int readings[]

---

Originally posted by [gustavo.velascoh](https://answers.ros.org/users/2667/gustavo.velascoh/) with karma: 756 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 8

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cbgrey](https://answers.ros.org/users/4978/cbgrey/) on 2013-05-26**:
Ah, it's the fact that different topics can share the same message type I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Topic is a channel - you are correct, but additionally to a name topic can transmit only the messages of a particular type. Thus, a message to be sent across this channel should have the same type.

Imagine that you have a square pipe (this will be a channel-topic) and a set of cubes (these are messages). All the cubes have same dimensions, but different colours, and even some of them have letters engraved. So the 'square' will be the type of a message and colours and letters will be the contents of that message. That means you cannot send (publish) or receive (subscribe to) 'circle' and 'triangle' messages on that topic.

---

Originally posted by [Boris](https://answers.ros.org/users/2873/boris/) with karma: 3060 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on 2017-08-26**:
Very intuitive, thank you

**Comment by [tuan](https://answers.ros.org/users/45785/tuan/) on 2019-09-18**:
Great answer.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

We have messages, and every message has a message type.

Now, every defined topic should have one of those types, so publishers/subscribers to the topic can send/receive messages, of different values but of the that same type, through the topic.

---

Originally posted by [amine23](https://answers.ros.org/users/3879/amine23/) with karma: 123 on 2013-05-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1